# Can i add columns my database and then add properties in my models corresponding to those columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC project which uses entity framework. I need to add some columns to my database. Is it possible to just write an SQL script to add columns to the database and then add some properties in my models that match the added columns? I kind of try to avoid code-first migrations here. Would my approach work? If not, what is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will work, but if you try to use migrations again in the future you may have problems, as the mechanism that tracks changes will not match your current setup

Comment: Avoiding the solution purposely designed to do what you ask is going to set you up for really big headaches in the future. Especially if you plan on actually having multiple environments, like test/train/live.

Comment: In my experience it is best to add columns on Database then delete them from EF diagram and re-add them,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. If your tables are following Entity Framework naming conventions, all you have to do is add new column and add new property in proper entity class with the same name as your new column.

```
public class Stuff{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //your new column in database is named "NewColumn"
    public string NewColumn { get; set; }
}
```

If you are not following this conventions, you should decorate your new property in entity class with [Column annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn) to explicitly tell Entity Framework where he should look for value for this property.

```
public class Stuff{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //your new column
    [Column("my_new_column")]
    public string NewColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid many migrations, you can simply add the properties first, run the `add-migration` command, followed by the `update-database`, and you will keep doing that for any new properties you need.
When you finally reach a state where you don't expect any changes, you can remove all the migrations created, and run the `add-migration` command again and then `update-database`, this will create a single file that has the whole database schema.
This is useful if you are still early in the development stage